# Datagridview checkbox cell change color of button and drawline

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview, colors

The issue was to change the color of a button by clicking a datagridview checkbox cell and additionally highlight a drawn arrow by the same checkbox click.

This is now working with the solution of TaW. Thanks for that.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object f_sender_dgv, DataGridViewCellEventArgs f_event_dgv)
    {     

        DataGridView dataGridView1 = f_sender_dgv as DataGridView;


        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);

        DataGridViewCell cb_1 = dataGridView1[2, 0];//
        //DataGridViewCell cb_1 = dataGridView1[f_event_dgv.ColumnIndex , f_event_dgv.RowIndex];

        if (cb_1 is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
        {
            bool c = (bool)(cb_1 as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value;
            button_gv_1.BackColor = c ? Color.Yellow : Color.Snow;
            button_v_5.BackColor = c ? Color.Yellow : Color.Snow;
        }
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Graphics g;
        g = e.Graphics;
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        myPen.Width = 1;
        myPen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
        //g.DrawLine(myPen1, 400, 700, 1000, 100);//(X_start, Y_start, X_ende, Y_ende)

        // test if data is loaded:
        if (!(dataGridView1.RowCount > 0 && dataGridView1.ColumnCount > 2)) return;

        //use the correct indices = [e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]
        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[2,0];  
        if (cell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell && cell.Value != null)
        {
            bool c = (bool)(cell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value;
            Pen myPen1 = c ? Pens.Yellow : Pens.Black;
            g.DrawLine(myPen1, 400, 700, 1000, 100);//(X_start, Y_start, X_ende, Y_ende)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What, if anything happens now when you click the check box? What is your code for the datagridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the equivalent code for the `button.BackColor`:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);

    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    if (cell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
    {
        bool c = (bool) (cell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value;
        button1.BackColor = c ? Color.Yellow: Color.Snow;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

The `Paint` event can either test the cell in more or less the same way:

```
protected override void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // test if data are loaded:
    if (! (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0  && dataGridView1dgv.ColumnCount > 2)) return;

    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[0, 2];  // <-- use the correct indices!!
    if (cell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell && cell.Value != null)
    {
        bool c = (bool)(cell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value;

        Pen myPen = c ? Pens.Yellow : Pens.Snow;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, 160, 285, 250, 285);
    }
}
```

.. or test a class level flag you set.

Comment: Thanks for your code. It works perfect in this minimal working example. Now I implemented it to the main code and it generates an error I cannot deal with. Do you have a clue where this comes from?

Comment: Nun, die Medung ist ja klar: Einer der Indizes ist zu groß; du musst einerseits die richtigen Indizes verwenden, die sehen ja ok aus; aber andererseits auch sicherstellen, dass überhaupt Daten gelden sind, sprich einen Test a la `if (! (dgv.RowCount > 0 and dgv.ColumnCount > 2)) return; ` oder ähnliches. Gerade das Paint Ereignis tritt ja schon vor dem Laden der Daten auf! - Ich hab die Antwort ergänzt..